# How to make a choice view on the iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I build a choice view something like the image below, or the stock picker from Apple for example.

I know I can make the 'normal' `UIPickerView` but this looks much better.

[image: something like that]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle: nil delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle: @"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle: nil otherButtonTitles: @"Take photo or video", @"Choose photo",… nil];
[actionSheet showInView: self.view);
```

---

*or in Swift*

```
    UIActionSheet(title: nil,
               delegate: nil,
      cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel",
 destructiveButtonTitle: nil,
      otherButtonTitles: "Take photo or video",  "Choose photo").showInView(self.view)
```

Comment: Glad to help! If you like it don't forget to accept the answer. Cheers!